# Simple issues causing multiple errors with basic Java Programing

Tags: java

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DateDifference
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    int firstMonthNumber = 0;int secondMonthNumber = 0;

    System.out.println("For the first date,");
    System.out.print("Enter month: ");
    String firstMonth = keyboard.next();
    System.out.print("Enter year: ");
    int firstYear = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("For the second date,");
    System.out.print("Enter month: ");
    String secondMonth = keyboard.next();
    System.out.print("Enter year: ");
    int secondYear = keyboard.nextInt();
    if (firstMonth.equalsIgnoreCase("January")) {
      firstMonthNumber = 1;
    } else if (firstMonth.equalsIgnoreCase("February")) {
      firstMonthNumber = 2;
    } else if (firstMonth.equalsIgnoreCase("March")) {
      firstMonthNumber = 3;
    } else if (firstMonth.equalsIgnoreCase("April")) {
      firstMonthNumber = 4;
    } else if (firstMonth.equalsIgnoreCase("May")) {
      firstMonthNumber = 5;
    } else if (firstMonth.equalsIgnoreCase("June")) {
      firstMonthNumber = 6;
    } else if (firstMonth.equalsIgnoreCase("July")) {
      firstMonthNumber = 7;
    } else if (firstMonth.equalsIgnoreCase("August")) {
      firstMonthNumber = 8;
    } else if (firstMonth.equalsIgnoreCase("September")) {
      firstMonthNumber = 9;
    } else if (firstMonth.equalsIgnoreCase("October")) {
      firstMonthNumber = 10;
    } else if (firstMonth.equalsIgnoreCase("November")) {
      firstMonthNumber = 11;
    } else {
      firstMonthNumber = 12;
    }
    if (secondMonth.equalsIgnoreCase("January")) {
      secondMonthNumber = 1;
    } else if (secondMonth.equalsIgnoreCase("February")) {
      secondMonthNumber = 2;
    } else if (secondMonth.equalsIgnoreCase("March")) {
      secondMonthNumber = 3;
    } else if (secondMonth.equalsIgnoreCase("April")) {
      secondMonthNumber = 4;
    } else if (secondMonth.equalsIgnoreCase("May")) {
      secondMonthNumber = 5;
    } else if (secondMonth.equalsIgnoreCase("June")) {
      secondMonthNumber = 6;
    } else if (secondMonth.equalsIgnoreCase("July")) {
      secondMonthNumber = 7;
    } else if (secondMonth.equalsIgnoreCase("August")) {
      secondMonthNumber = 8;
    } else if (secondMonth.equalsIgnoreCase("September")) {
      secondMonthNumber = 9;
    } else if (secondMonth.equalsIgnoreCase("October")) {
      secondMonthNumber = 10;
    } else if (secondMonth.equalsIgnoreCase("November")) {
      secondMonthNumber = 11;
    } else {
      secondMonthNumber = 12;
    }
    int monthDifference;
    int yearDifference;
    int monthDifference;
    if (firstYear > secondYear)
    {
      int yearDifference = firstYear - secondYear;
      monthDifference = firstMonthNumber - secondMonthNumber;
    }
    else
    {
      int monthDifference;
      if (firstYear < secondYear)
      {
        int yearDifference = secondYear - firstYear;
        monthDifference = secondMonthNumber - firstMonthNumber;
      }
      else
      {
        yearDifference = 0;
        monthDifference = Math.abs(secondMonthNumber - firstMonthNumber);
      }
    }
    if (monthDifference < 0)
    {
      yearDifference--;
      monthDifference += 12;
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("These dates are " + yearDifference + " years and " + monthDifference + " months apart.");
  }
}

Errors:DateDifferencesFinderProject.java:107: error: variable MonthDifference is already defined in method main(String[])
    int MonthDifference;
        ^
DateDifferencesFinderProject.java:110: error: variable YearDifference is already defined in method main(String[])
          int YearDifference = firstYear - secondYear;
              ^
DateDifferencesFinderProject.java:115: error: variable MonthDifference is already defined in method main(String[])
      int MonthDifference;
          ^
DateDifferencesFinderProject.java:118: error: variable YearDifference is already defined in method main(String[])
            int YearDifference = secondYear - firstYear;
                ^
4 errors
```

So I thought I was done with the code behind my intro to computer programming project but then I ran into these simple errors. I'm having a hard time understanding the errors the compiler is giving me. why does a previously defined variable cause issues for the compiler?. Whats the issue causing the problem for the compiler? what can I do to solve the errors? I know I'm a complete noob when it comes to this sort of thing, but i just spent the last hour looking at these errors tearing my hair out. If someone could please point me in the right direction, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you say `int foo` it declares a variable in the current scope. If there is another `int foo` in the same scope, it's a duplicate variable declaration.

Remove all additional declarations on the lines indicated in the error. They're unneeded.

Comment: I'm not seeing where I declared anything using int foo?

Comment: `Foo` and `bar` are just common placeholders. One of your "foos" is `monthDifference`.

Comment: oh okay, i'm not all that experienced thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: thanks for the help. I removed the four reused variables and everything is now all cleared up. once again thanks user Kayaman for the assistance with my noob question.

Comment: You're welcome. That's (one of the reasons) why I'm here.

Comment: @R.Isaac Can you accept the answer if it solved your problem?